# How to write raw json data [as pyhon Dictionary] to Google cloud storage using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, google-bucket

My use case is very simple, I'm fetching raw JSON response form my REST API and keeping it as dictionary in python, i have to write this data into google cloud storage. is there any approach other than "upload_from_string" option ?

Answer (score 3):

For uploading data to Cloud Storage, you have [only 3 methods in Python blobs object](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html):

- Blob.upload_from_file()
- Blob.upload_from_filename()
- Blob.upload_from_string()

From dict, it's up to you to choose to convert it into a string and use `upload_from_string` method. Or you can also store it locally, in the `/tmp` directory (in memory file system), and then use `file` purpose methods.

You maybe have more capabilities with files, if you want to zip the content and/or use dedicated library that dump a dict into a file.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar use case. I want to throw some data, which is in a dictionary format into a google cloud storage bucket.

I'm assuming you already have created a bucket(it is a simple task if you are trying to do it programmatically).

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
import os

def upload_to_gcloud(data: dict):
    """
    this function take a dictionary as input and uploads
    it in a google cloud storage bucket
    """          
    
    ## your service-account credentials as JSON file
    os.environ['GOOLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTAILS'] = "YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-CREDENTIALS-AS-JSON"
    
    ## instane of the storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    ## instance of a bucket in your google cloud storage
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("your-bucket-name")
    
    ## if you want to create a new file 
    blob = bucket.blob("filename-you-want-here")

    ## if there already exists a file
    blob = bucket.get_blob("filename-of-that-file")

    ## uploading data using upload_from_string method
    ## json.dumps() serializes a dictionary object as string
    blob.upload_from_string(json.dumps(data))
```

this approach will work with any data which you can pose as a string. if you want to directly upload a file from your local filesystem, use upload_from_filename() instead.

Hope this helps!!